# Problem compiling C-Function to Postgres; compiler didn't find postgres.h

Tags: c, postgresql, gcc

I was asked to create a C-Function to integrate with Postgres. The Postgres documentation to this kind of function is available here: [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html).

The function I am trying to compile is from the manual and it is called `add_one`, just for test. But I had a problem while compiling it. The command I followed of the documentation was:

```
cc -fPIC -c foo.c
cc -shared -o foo.so foo.o
```

And the problem it returned was:

```
[igoralberte@localhost inside-postgres]$ cc -fPIC -c serializacao.c 
serializacao.c:1:10: fatal error: postgres.h: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
 #include "postgres.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

In English, it means: Non-existent file or directory (postgres.h).

I have tried to copy some files I thought were important to `/usr/lib` directory. They were on `/usr/include/pgsql` or on `/lib64`. Those files were:

- libpq.so
- libpq.so.5
- libpq.so.5.13
- libpq (directory)
- postgres_ext.h

Some important informations about my system:

- I am using CentOS 8
- System architecture: x86-64
- GCC version: gcc (GCC) 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)
- Postgres version: 13.3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't copy/move files around that are managed by your package manager. You *will* mess up your system. The only files that are safe to touch are mostly under `/home/igoralberte` and, if you know what you are doing, `/etc`, `/usr/local`.

Comment: I just made a copy... I hope it doesn't mess up my system haha But I will undo it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bold step to write a postgres plugin before you have a solid grasp on linux/unix, shell programming and how to compile c programs.

Typically your c compiler has to be told where to find header files using the `-I` compiler switch. So if `postgres.h` is in `/path/containing/headerfile`, you must add `-I/path/containing/headerfile` to the compile command:

```
cc -I/path/containing/headerfile -fPIC -c foo.c
```

The postgres documentation you linked to tells you to use `pg_config --includedir-server` to find out where the the header files are stored.

I am not familiar with `pg_config`, but if it acts like similar tools and
gives the output `-I/path/containing/headerfile` when calling it with the paramater `--includedir-server`, then you don't have to hardcode the path in your compile command. But just write:

```
cc `pg_config --includedir-server` -fPIC -c foo.c
```

See "Command Substitution" in your favorite shell documentation.

I also recommend learning how to use a build-tool like `make`. Things are soon going to be tedious if you have to retype compilation and link commands all the time.

Oh, and by the way, you probably want to write `#include <postgres.h>` and not `#include "postgres.h"` (Unless you are a postgres contributor and `postgres.h` is part of your project files)